# comparar dos tablas mysql y obtener registros que coincidan y los que no

Tags: php, mysqli

buenas estoy intentando consultar mis dos tablas en la base de datos una se llama ( pagos_pagina) el cual se llena con un formulario de pago y la otra es (archivos_pagos) que cual se llena con subir un archivo csv. ambas tablas tienen filas iguales y quiero comparar las filas ( monto y referencia) y mostrar en una tabla los que coinsiden y los que no coinsiden a modo de saber quienes pagaron ese mes y quienes no. aqui les dejo mi codigo.

```js
<?php
                    //Clase para manejar la conexion a la base de datos
                    class Connect
                    {
                        private $user = "root";//usuario de mysqlk
                        private $pass = "";//clave de mysql ( aqui no tengo clave de el servidor)
                        private $base = "radius";//base de datos en mysql
                        private $server = "localhost";//servidor de alojamiento
                        public $error;//en caso de error se almacena aqui
                        public $db;
                        public function __construct(){
                            $mysqli = new mysqli($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->base);
                            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                                $this->error = "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                            }
                            $this->db = $mysqli;
                        }
                    }
                    //Clase trabajo que se extiende de Connect
                    class Trabajo extends Connect
                    {
                        public function __construct(){
                            parent::__construct();
                        }
                        public function valida($x){
                            $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pagos_pagina WHERE referencia = '$x' ");
                            $t = $a->num_rows();
                            if($t===1){
                                //Si el cliente realizó el pago retorno la información
                                $row = $a->fetch_object();
                                return $row;
                            }else{
                                //si no retorno falso
                                return false;
                            }
                        }//
                        public function data(){
                            $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM archivos_pagos");
                            $row = $a->fetch_array();
                            foreach($row as $item){
                                //Envío a validar la referencia del cliente
     
                                $valida = $this->valida($item['referencia']);
                                if($valida){
                                    //Si existe el pago muestro la información
                                    echo "El Cliente ".$item['referencia']." Realizo el pago de ".$valida->monto." en fecha ".$valida->fecha;
                                }else{
                                    //Si no existe informo que dicho pago no se ha realizado
                                    echo "El Cliente ".$item['referencia']." no ha realizado el pago";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $p = new trabajo();
                    var_dump($p->data());
                    ?>
```

me da el siguiente error

> (Warning: Illegal string offset 'referencia' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\superconex\login\prueba.php on line 402)  mi linea 402
>   es ($valida = $this->valida($item['referencia']);)  y me da este error
>   (Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\superconex\login\prueba.php on line 386) 
>   mi linea 386es

```
($t = $a->num_rows();)
```

he intentado con todo y nada no encuentro obtener lo que quiero tampoco se que estoy haciendo mal porfa suplico su gran ayuda y enorme conocimiento

Comment: $t = $a->num_rows;Prueba esto sin (). Ademas te recomiendo utilizar un if antes para comprobar que la consulta es valida.

Comment: Para empezar, prueba cambiar, dentro de tu método `data()`, la línea `$row = $a->fetch_array();` por `$row = $a->fetch_assoc();`, ya que al usar el primer método obtienes un arreglo numerado, en cambio en el segundo método obtienes un arreglo asociativo, y allí sí encontrarás la columna `referencia` que buscas...

Comment: Saantty estas casi cerca . quite los paréntesis y me dio un resultado. El Cliente 1 no ha realizado el pago ,El Cliente 2 no ha realizado el pago ,El Cliente 3 no ha realizado el pago . solo eso me dio. y me dio el mismo error (Warning: Illegal string offset 'referencia' in C:\xampp\htdocs\superconex\login\prueba.php on line 407) esta es la linea'$valida = $this->valida($item['referencia']);' y este otro (Warning: Illegal string offset 'referencia' in C:\xampp\htdocs\superconex\login\prueba.php on line 413) esta es la linea ' echo "El Cliente ".$item['referencia']." no ha realizado el pago";'

Comment: quinqui probe y no paso nada siguio el mismo error y gracias de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda